# Throw of a die in Java

Tags: java

The throw of a die is a popular program in Java,

```
public class Die {

    /*  This program simulates rolling a die */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int die;   // The number on the die.
        die = (int)(Math.random()*6 + 1);
        System.out.println (die);         
    } // end main()
} // end class
```

What I wish to do is make it repeat, 500 times. I have not been able to put this program into a loop of 500. I usually program in Python, thus I guess my Java has rusted !

Any help is most welcome !

Comment: @BalusC Did you see the part where "die" is singular and "dice" is plural?

Comment: @Etaoin: Oh! I always thought it was dice-dices. I'll rollback it. Many thanks for noting.

Comment: @Arkapravo: I'm glad you decided to ask here instead of copying the code and pasting it 499 times.  Good for you.

Comment: @Mark Rushakoff: I was actually hitting 'UP arrow' and 'Enter' in the command-line, after about 227 such attempts my fingers started to pain ! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Die {
    /** This program simulates rolling a die */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

       int die;   // The number on the die.

       for(int i = 0; i < 500; i++){
           die = (int)(Math.random()*6 + 1);
           System.out.println (die);    
       }    
    }  // end main()
}  // end class
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `for` statement for this. Learn more about it at [this Sun tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html).

E.g.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    // This will be executed 500 times.
}
```

Answer (score 6):

It's a little weird to forget how to do a loop, but here's my solution:

```
Random r = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 500; ++i) {
    int die = r.nextInt(6) + 1; // integer in range [1, 6]
    System.out.println(die);
}
```

Notice that I use Random.nextInt() instead of Math.random(). There are several reasons for that in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738629/math-random-versus-random-nextintint)

Hope that helps :)

Comment: @Po : yeah, it is weird .... but I spent a fair amount of time and got to nothing .... guess it is the Python effect !