# Why doesn't (int) Math.random()*10 produce 10 in Java?

Tags: java

Why the following produce between 0 - 9 and not 10?

My understanding is Math.random() create number between 0 to under 1.0.

So it can produce 0.99987 which becomes 10 by *10, isn't it?

```
int targetNumber = (int) (Math.random()* 10);
```

Comment: You should be using Random.nextInt() to get "better" random numbers anyway: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/738629/math-random-versus-random-nextintint/738651#738651

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Casting a `double` to an `int` in Java does integer truncation. This means that if your random number is 0.99987, then multiplying by 10 gives 9.9987, and integer truncation gives 9.

Answer (score 14):

From the Math javadoc :

"a pseudorandom double greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0"

1.0 is not a posible value with Math.random. So you can't obtain 10. And (int) 9.999 gives 9

Answer (score 2):

Cause **(Math.random()* 10** gets rounded down using **int()**, so **int(9.9999999)** yields **9**.

Answer (score 1):

Because `(int)` rounds down.
`(int)9.999` results in 9.
//integer truncation

Comment: There is a typo, (int)0.999 results in 0

Answer (score 0):

> 0.99987 which becomes 10 by *10

Not when I went to school. It becomes 9.9987.

Answer (score 0):

Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1

Now you get a integer number between 1 and 10, including the number 10.

Answer (score 0):

You could always tack on a +1 to the end of the command, allowing it to add 1 to the generated number. So, you would have something like this:

```
int randomnumber = ( (int)(Math.random( )*10) +1);
```

This would generate any integer between 1 and 10.

If you wanted any integer between 0 and 10, you could do this:

```
int randomnumber = ( (int)(Math.random( )*11) -1);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

you can add 1 to the equation so the output will be from 1 to 10 instead of 0 to 9
like this :

```
int targetNumber = (int) (Math.random()* 10+1);
```