# Why there is a function as well as a class for random numbers in Java?

Tags: java, random

In Java there is a function  `Math.random()` as well as a class `Random`. Why there are two entities for the seemingly same operation(ie *Random number generation*) and which one should be used when?

Comment: Possible double-post of, there ism ore than just the seed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/738629/math-random-versus-random-nextintint

Comment: Not a duplicate, the other question is explicitely about sampling integers via `Math.random()*n`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need to set an explicit random seed (yes you do that sometimes, when you want reproducible random numbers), then you use `Random`.

Apart from that, the `random()` method is just a shortcut to a fixed `Random` object, so you use that for brevity and when you don't care about the random seed (which is most of the time, i guess).

Answer (score 2):

The 'difference' is that java.util.Random has methods to return more than one type of
number. No casting needed. One constructor lets the user seed the generator for repeating sequences.

java.lang.Math.random() uses java.util.Random. It provides only doubles and has no seeding capability.