# math.random, only generating a 0?

Tags: java

The following code is only producing a 0 ;-;

What am I doing wrong?

```
public class RockPaperSci {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Rock 1
    //Paper 2
    //Scissors 3
    int croll =1+(int)Math.random()*3-1;
    System.out.println(croll);
  }
}
```

Edit, Another Poster suggested something that fixed it.
int croll = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 4 - 1);

Thanks, everyone!

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random%28%29 Math.random returns a double between 0.0 and 1.0 , so the integer Value of it is always O.

Comment: see http://bmanolov.free.fr/javaoperators.php casts have higher precedence than other operations

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You are using [`Math.random()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#random()) which states

> Returns a `double` value with a positive sign, greater than or
>   equal to `0.0` and less than `1.0`.

You are casting the result to an `int`, which returns the integer part of the value, thus `0`.

Then `1 + 0 - 1 = 0`.

Consider using `java.util.Random`

```
Random rand = new Random();
System.out.println(rand.nextInt(3) + 1);
```

Answer (score 6):

`Math.random()` generates double values between range - `[0.0, 1.0)`. And then you have typecasted the result to an `int`:

```
(int)Math.random()   // this will always be `0`
```

And then multiply by `3` is `0`. So, your expression is really:

```
1 + 0 - 1
```

---

I guess you want to put parenthesis like this:

```
1 + (int)(Math.random() * 3)
```

---

Having said that, you should really use [`Random#nextInt(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) method if you want to generate integer values in some range. It is more efficient than using `Math#random()`.

You can use it like this:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int croll = 1 + rand.nextInt(3);
```

**See also:**

- [Math.random() versus Random.nextInt(int)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/738629/1679863)

Comment: I think you meant 1 + (int)(Math.random() * 3)

Comment: @SpiderPig Depends. It is really not clear what number OP want to generate. But I'll let him decide for himself. Thanks :)

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ I've put the parenthesis like that only. And the output would not always be 0 in that case.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ No issues :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static double random()
```

Returns a double value with a positive sign, greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0. Returned values are chosen pseudorandomly with (approximately) uniform distribution from that range.

```
 int croll =1+(int)Math.random()*3-1;
```

eg

```
 int croll =1+0*-1; 


System.out.println(croll); // will print always 0
```

Answer (score 0):

All our mates explained you reasons of  unexpected output you got.

Assuming you want generate a random `croll`

Consider `Random` for resolution

```
    Random rand= new Random();
    double croll = 1 + rand.nextInt() * 3 - 1;
    System.out.println(croll);
```