# Math.random() v/s Random class

Tags: java, random

The `Math` class in Java has a method, `Math.random()` which returns a pseudorandom number between 0 and 1.
There is also a class `java.util.Random` which has various methods like `nextInt()`, `nextFloat()`, `nextDouble()`, `nextLong()`etc.

My question is that if I want to get a random number in a range (say, 30-70), then which way should I go? The factors under consideration are **speed** and **randomness**.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/738629/math-random-versus-random-nextintint?lq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the implementation of `Math.random()`, you'll see that it uses an instance of the `Random` class :

```
public static double random() {
    return RandomNumberGeneratorHolder.randomNumberGenerator.nextDouble();
}

private static final class RandomNumberGeneratorHolder {
    static final Random randomNumberGenerator = new Random();
}
```

Therefore the randomness would be the same.

That said, since you need an `int` and not a `double`, you'd better use the `nextInt` method of the `Random` class, since it would save you the multiplication and casting of a `double` to `int`.

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int num = rnd.nextInt(41)+30;
```

Answer (score 0):

Math.random() does rely on the Random class. Depending on the case and data type you are using you can use either. For an `int` Random.nextInt() would probably be the best choice.

Speaking of randomness, a more secure random class is SecureRandom. SecureRandom does not rely on the system time unlike Random, so if your application has a security element to it definitely use SecureRandom. Same method names, except

`SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom()` instead of

`Random random = new Random()`.

Comment: In which package is `SecureRandom` located?

Comment: @PriydarshiSingh java.security.SecureRandom

Answer (score 0):

I personally would go with the random class, because, in my opinion, it's way easier to use and to influence with parameters, for example for a random number between 30-79

`Random r = new Random();                           int i = r.nextInt(40)+30;`

I hope that helped at least a bit