# How to print a random character from a string?

Tags: java

I have an assignment due and the last part of the assignment asks:

> Suppose s is any string. Write a sequence of statements that will print a random character from s.

Here is what I have come up with so far:

```
for(int j = 0; j < s.length(); j++){
}
int l = ((int)Math.random()*s.length());
char ch = s.charAt(l);
System.out.println(ch);
```

I think these are the basic concepts I need to learn how to understand/use to write this code successfully. What I am confused on is where these specific lines of code go, for example if the charAt method should come before the loop, etc.

Comment: Have you tried your code? Does it do what you want? (Does taking the loop out make any difference?)

Comment: You might want to change the `int l` line to `int l = (int) (Math.random()*s.length());`, since the current line will always generate zero.

Comment: Thank you all, turns out I didn't need the loop piece in there. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost had it already. I think your main issue was this part:

```
int l = ((int)Math.random()*s.length());
```

Your `(int)` cast is misplaced. If you read the [javadoc of `Math.random()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random--) you see that it returns a double value "greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0". Casting values of this range to `int` (i.e. simply cutting off all decimal places) will always result in `0`, which only prints the first character of the string.

The solution is to first multiply it with the string's length and do the cast afterwards:

```
int l = (int)(Math.random()*s.length());
```

If you only want to print *one* random character, you don't need a loop of any sort, so you can delete that from your code.

See [this fiddle](https://ideone.com/XEn76B) for a working example. What you still need to do is think about how to get the input string (hint: maybe read it from `System.in`).

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    String s = "foobar42";
    int l = (int)(Math.random()*s.length());
    char ch = s.charAt(l);
    System.out.println(ch);
}
```

And to finally show off in class, you could also have a look at the [`Random`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) class which could replace the above line with something like

```
int l = new Random().nextInt(s.length());
```

and see if you can grasp [the difference between those two approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738629/math-random-versus-random-nextintint). Although that is completely irrelevant to your assignment and way out of scope.

Comment: Thank you! This helps a lot.

Comment: Hi Marvin - how do I mark the answer as accepted? I can't find that button. Thank you again,

Answer (score 1):

You can get a random character by using s.charAt(x), where x is a random number between 0 and the length of the String-1.

The code for this is as follows:

```
String s = "text string";
Random rand = new Random();
int randomIndex = rand.nextInt(s.length());//returns a random number between 0 and the index of the last character of the string
System.out.println(s.charAt(randomIndex));
```

When you need to do this several times, you just put it in a loop like this:

```
String s = "text string";

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { //prints 10 random characters from the String
    Random rand = new Random();
    int randomIndex = rand.nextInt(s.length());//returns a random number between 0 and the index of the last character of the string
    System.out.println(s.charAt(randomIndex));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach:

```
String s = "hello world";
System.out.println(Character.toString(s.charAt((new Random()).nextInt(s.length()))));
```

- the `s.length()` returns the size of `s`;
- the `(new Random()).nextInt` returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive);
- the `s.charAt` returns the character at the position specified
- the `Character.toString` returns the string representation of the specified character

Comment: nextInt() is not a static method, so you cannot access it via the Random class.

Comment: @KrasimirStoev, true! Thanks for the repair.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
System.out.println(s.charAt((int)(Math.random() * s.length())));
```