# How to get a random number in a range using Math.random()

Tags: java, math, random

I'm not too familiar with `Math.random();` and I don't know what to do for the conditions that I want. I want to produce a random integer between 0 and 52 so far this is what I have set up.

```
    public class Tester{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int size=52;
        while(size>0){
            int rando=(int)Math.random()*size;
            size--;
            System.out.println(rando);
        }
    }
}
```

My code prints out all 0's until the condition of the while loop is met. I wanted to know how I would produce a random integer between 0 and 52. I understand that `Math.random();` produces a double and I think theres a problem with the type casting. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You only cast Math.random(). Its a value between 0 and 1 (excluding 1).
If you cast this it's zero anyway.

Cast the whole expression:
`(int)(Math.random()*size);`

BTW:
Your interval is only from 0 to 51 (because of the excluding 1.

Use `(int)(Math.random()*(size+1));`, if you want 0...52 as your interval.

Comment: Is there any way to prevent the Math.random(); from repeating what it already produced?

Comment: No, but you could save yout values in a Set and test if the value is already in the set.

Answer (score 3):

The cast takes precedence over the multiplication. Since `Math.random()` returns a double in the range [0.0..1.0), it will always be converted to `0`, and the result of multiplying that by any other `int` will of course be `0`. You could perform the multiplication before casting - (`(int)(Math.random()*size)`), but really it'd be easier to use [`Random.nextInt(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-).

Answer (score 2):

Math.random() returns a pseudo-random number with a domain of [0 , 1).

In the line:

```
int rando=(int)Math.random()*size;
```

this value is cast as an int and then multiplied by size.
To fix the problem with only printing zeros you need to add parentheses.

```
int rando = (int) (Math.random()*size);
```

This will only give you numbers in the domain [0, 51)
To fix this:

```
int rando = (int) (Math.random()* (size + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Necessary to use the Math class?

a simpler way to find this number would using the Random class

Example:

```
Random randomNumber = new Random ();
System.out.println(randomNumber.nextInt(53));
```

**See also:**

[Math.random() versus Random.nextInt(int)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738629/math-random-versus-random-nextintint)

Answer (score 0):

You can use another code like java.util.Random:

```
Random r = new Random();
int rando = r.nextInt(53); //inclusive 0 and exclusive 53
```

In case of Math.random() and your code, you have to cast after the multiplication (set the brackets like below):

```
int rando = (int)(Math.random() * size);
```

In your code, the return value of Math.random() gets casted first and then it is multiplied with the size-parameter. Because Math.random() return double between 0 and 1, the cast to int returns 0.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Math.random() to generate a random integer within a range of numbers, as seen in the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random()). 
But you may use the `Random` class comming in the `java.util` package, and use the method `.nextInt()` or more specifically `.nextInt(int maximum)` where maximum will be **53**, not 52 because as [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)) state, the method is exclusive. 

If you want a number between a specific range like 10 and 50, you may construct a method like this:

```
 private final Random RANDOMISER = new Random();

 private int generateRandomNumber(int from, int to){
  return RANDOMISER.nextInt((to+1)-from)+from;
 }
```