# How to create array in method to print random number desired by user?

Tags: java, arrays

I wrote the code to create user desired number of array and size, but there is no any random number displayed.

```
public class ArrayStats {
    public static void fillRandomArray(int [] a, int max) {
        int [] randomArray = new int[max];
        for (int i=0; i < randomArray.length; i++){
            randomArray[i] = (int)(Math.random());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where you use the array variable int [] a?. You need fill the array a[] with the result randomArray ?

Comment: how to fill the array a[] with the random array?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Math.random() return a Double value from 0.0 to 1.0
0.1 to int = 0, ....... 0.5 to int = 0 .
If you need generate random number try it:

```
    public static int randomNumber(int min, int max) {

            Random rand = new Random();
            int num = rand.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
            return num;

        }

 public static void fillRandomArray(int [] a, int max) {
        int [] randomArray = new int[max];
        for (int i=0; i < randomArray.length; i++){

            //Example Generate random number between 1 and 9
            randomArray[i] = randomNumber(1,9);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tiny modification to your code, that would fill your array with random ints from 0 to Integer.MAX_VALUE:

```
public class ArrayStats {
    public static void fillRandomArray(int [] a, int max) {
        int [] randomArray = new int[max];
        for (int i=0; i < randomArray.length; i++){
            randomArray[i] = (int)(Math.random() * Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        }
    }
}
```

The thing here is that `Math.random()` returns a double in the range from 0 to 1. When you were casting it to (int) it always turned 0.

Alternatively you can take a look at class `Random`.

Answer (score 0):

The random values aren't stored because function `Math.random()` generates values between 0.0 (inclusive) and 1.0 (exclusive) and hence, cast to int will always return 0. From official docs:

> Returns a double value with a positive sign, greater than or equal to
>   0.0 and less than 1.0. Returned values are chosen pseudorandomly with (approximately) uniform distribution from that range.

Either multiply the `Math.random()` result with some fixed integer value and cast to int or use a `Random` instance's method `random.nextInt()` as:

```
int rand = (int)(Math.random() * FIXED_INT_VAL);
```

or

```
Random r = new Random();
int rand = r.nextInt();
```

The latter approach is recommend due to reason explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/738651/6348498).

So, your code becomes:

```
public class ArrayStats {
    public static void fillRandomArray(int [] a, int max) {
        int [] randomArray = new int[max];
        Random r = new Random();
        for (int i=0; i < randomArray.length; i++){
            randomArray[i] = r.nextInt();
        }
    }
}
```