# Generating specific number in a random way in Java

Tags: java, random

I would like to generate `50` integers randomly taken from `7`, `15` and `35`.  I understand we can specify the range using

```
int random = (int )(Math. random() * 50 + 1)
```

will generate an integer from `1-50` but how can generate only `7`, `15` or `35`?

Comment: Actually, this is not a good way of generating a range. It is biased.

Comment: Trying to find something to back that claim up, in meantime, this is how you can get a range in a better way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-integers-in-a-specific-range

Comment: Found evidence of why this approach is biased: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/738629/math-random-versus-random-nextintint