# Java Random number between 100 and 500 which is a multiple of 10

Tags: java, random

I want to generate random number between two numbers which are multiples of 10.
For example, between 100 and 500, I want to generate a uniform distribution of 110, 120 ... 490, 500.

I think it is better to use Random.nextInt() as per [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738629/math-random-versus-random-nextintint) post. But not sure how to do that.

Comment: With a bit of arithmetic, `(Random.nextInt(40) + 10) * 10`gives you what you want, I think.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `(Random.nextInt(40) + 11) * 10` because yours generates a distribution over 100, 110 ... 480, 490?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this function.

```
public int random()
{
     Random r=new Random();
     return (r.nextInt(41)+10)*10;
}
```

Read this [Math.random() versus Random.nextInt(int)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738629/math-random-versus-random-nextintint)

> Random.nextInt(n) is both more efficient and less biased than
>   Math.random() * n

Comment: Do I need to instantiate Random every time ?

Comment: No not needed. In fact, re instantiate might increase duplicate rate!

Comment: You have to declare it as static inside the class. (not inside the function)

Answer (score 1):

**(Random.nextInt(41)+10)*10** is the correct answer. The Random.nextInt(41) will generate numbers between 0 to 40. The Random.nextInt(41)+10 will generate number from 0 to 50.

And Hence (Random.nextInt(41)+10)*10 will generate numbers between 100 and 500.Please note that 100 and 500 are also included in the result.

Comment: These are random numbers b/w 100 and 500. There will not be the guaranteed behavior of uniformity.