# I am supposed to be generating random numbers, however if you run it, im getting more a lot of repeats is, that natural or did i mess up?

Tags: java, random, numbers

I am supposed to be generating an array with 1000 numbers in it and then bubble sorting it. the output i get has quite a bit of repeated numbers, a little too much and i feel like i have messed up. I am still learning so go easy on me:)

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    Random rd = new Random();
int[] arr = new int[1000];

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
    arr[i] = (int)(Math.random()*1000+1);



int n = arr.length;
int temp = 0;

for(int z=0; z < n; z++){
for(int j=1; j < (n-z); j++){                        
   if(arr[j-1] > arr[j]){

        temp = arr[j-1];
        arr[j-1] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = temp;

   }                    
   }
   }


    System.out.println(arr[i]);
```

Comment: You're not using `rd`, why do you instantiate it? Other than that, what do you mean you get too many repeated numbers? Have you calculated any probabilities that suggest that what you're seeing would be unlikely assuming you were randomizing right?

Comment: Why are you initializing a Random object (rd) but not using it?
The Random class is better than Math.random(). See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738629/math-random-versus-random-nextintint

Comment: Your generating 1000 random numbers between 1 and 1000, it is almost guaranteed that your gonna have some duplicates. If you dont want duplicates, generate a sorted array with a 1000 numbers, then shuffle it.

Comment: You should expect to get duplicate values, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem.  In fact, the probability of at least one duplicate value is around 0.99 by the time you've sampled 100 values in the range [1, 1000].

Comment: thank you all so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main issue is that you are still initializing your array while you are attempting to sort through it.  The following approach seems to give what you expected.

I wrote a quick little solution using the Random class that I find to be a little cleaner since it already has a .nextInt that you can seed with a max value you can visually make it a little cleaner.

```
    static void myRandom() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int[] arr = new int[1000];

        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            arr[i] = rand.nextInt(1000) + 1;
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You probably don't want to use the phrase "seed with a max value" to discuss parameterizing the range.  Seed has a very specific meaning in the context of PRNGs.