# How to randomly distribute mines for a Minesweeper program

Tags: java, random, distribution, minesweeper

I've gotten up to Test 9/10 of the autochecker and have made my programming now 333 lines of Java code, as per the course requirement (being written in Java, not over XXX amount of lines).  Basically, we need to draw a Minesweeper board with the mines shown as "*"s and the other cells showing a count of mines in the surrounding 1 cell areas around them. Here is my code:

```
public class Minesweeper {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {

        int m = Integer.parseInt( args[0] );
        int n = Integer.parseInt( args[1] );
        int k = Integer.parseInt( args[2] );
        int[][] gridArray = new int[m][n];
        int[][] mineArray = new int[m][n];
        int[][] placedMines = new int[k][2];
        int totalCells = m * n;
        int randomRow = (int) (Math.random() * m);
        int randomColumn = (int) (Math.random() * n);

        //Place mines...
        for (int i = 0; i <= k - 1; i++) {

            int pos = 0;

            while (true) {

                if (pos <= k - 1) {

                    if ((randomRow == placedMines[pos][0]) && (randomColumn == placedMines[pos][1])) {

                        if( ( k == totalCells ) && ( pos == k - 1 ) ) {

                            break;

                        } else {

                            randomRow = (int) (Math.random() * m);
                            randomColumn = (int) (Math.random() * n);
                            pos = 0;

                        }

                    } else {

                        pos++;

                    }

                    //System.out.println( "Gotten " + pos + "!" );

                } else {

                    break;

                }

            }

            mineArray[randomRow][randomColumn] = 1;
            placedMines[i][0] = randomRow;
            placedMines[i][1] = randomColumn;

        }

        //Place Kth mine...
        if( k == totalCells ) {

            for( int y = 0; y <= m - 1; y++ ) {

                for( int x = 0; x <= n - 1; x++ ) {

                    if( mineArray[y][x] == 0 ) {

                        mineArray[y][x] = 1;
                        placedMines[placedMines.length - 1][0] = y;
                        placedMines[placedMines.length - 1][1] = x;
                        break;

                    }

                }

            }

        }

        //Get numbers...
        for( int y = 0; y <= m - 1; y++ ) {

            for (int x = 0; x <= n - 1; x++) {

                if (mineArray[y][x] == 1) {

                    if ( y == 0 ) {

                        if (x == 0) {

                            if( n > 1 ) {

                                gridArray[y][x + 1]++;

                            }

                            if( m > 1 ) {

                                gridArray[y + 1][x]++;

                                if( n > 1 ) {

                                    gridArray[y + 1][x + 1]++;

                                }

                            }

                        } else if ((x > 0) && (x <= n - 2)) {

                            if( m > 1 ) {

                                gridArray[y + 1][x]++;

                                if( n > 1 ) {

                                    gridArray[y + 1][x + 1]++;
                                    gridArray[y + 1][x - 1]++;

                                }

                            }

                            if( n > 1 ) {

                                gridArray[y][x - 1]++;
                                gridArray[y][x + 1]++;

                            }

                        } else if (x == n - 1) {

                            if( n > 1 ) {

                                gridArray[y][x - 1]++;

                            }

                            if( m > 1 ) {

                                gridArray[y + 1][x]++;

                                if( n > 1 ) {

                                    gridArray[y + 1][x - 1]++;

                                }

                            }

                        }

                    } else if ((y > 0) && (y <= m - 2)) {

                        if (x == 0) {

                            if( m > 1 ) {

                                gridArray[y - 1][x]++;
                                gridArray[y + 1][x]++;

                                if( n > 1 ) {

                                    gridArray[y - 1][x + 1]++;
                                    gridArray[y + 1][x + 1]++;

                                }


                            }

                            if( n > 1 ) {

                                gridArray[y][x + 1]++;

                            }

                        } else if ((x > 0) && (x <= n - 2)) {

                            if( n > 1 ) {

                                gridArray[y][x - 1]++;
                                gridArray[y][x + 1]++;

                            }

                            if( m > 1 ) {


                                gridArray[y - 1][x]++;
                                gridArray[y + 1][x]++;

                                if( n > 1 ) {

                                    gridArray[y - 1][x - 1]++;
                                    gridArray[y - 1][x + 1]++;
                                    gridArray[y + 1][x + 1]++;
                                    gridArray[y + 1][x - 1]++;

                                }

                            }

                        } else if (x == n - 1) {

                            if( n > 1 ) {

                                gridArray[y][x - 1]++;

                            }

                            if( m > 1 ) {

                                gridArray[y - 1][x]++;
                                gridArray[y + 1][x]++;

                                if( n > 1 ) {

                                    gridArray[y - 1][x - 1]++;
                                    gridArray[y + 1][x - 1]++;

                                }

                            }

                        }

                    } else if (y == m - 1) {

                        if (x == 0) {

                            if( m > 1 ) {

                                gridArray[y - 1][x]++;

                                if( n > 1 ) {

                                    gridArray[y - 1][x + 1]++;

                                }

                            }

                            if( n > 1 ) {

                                gridArray[y][x + 1]++;

                            }

                        } else if ((x > 0) && (x <= n - 2)) {

                            if( m > 1 ) {

                                gridArray[y - 1][x]++;

                            }

                            if( n > 1 ) {

                                gridArray[y][x - 1]++;
                                gridArray[y][x + 1]++;

                                if( m > 1 ) {

                                    gridArray[y - 1][x - 1]++;
                                    gridArray[y - 1][x + 1]++;

                                }

                            }

                        } else if (x == n - 1) {

                            if( n > 1 ) {

                                gridArray[y][x - 1]++;

                            }

                            if( m > 1 ) {

                                gridArray[y - 1][x]++;

                                if( n > 1 ) {

                                    gridArray[y - 1][x - 1]++;

                                }

                            }

                        }

                    }

                }

            }

        }

        for( int y = 0; y <= m - 1; y++ ) {

            for( int x = 0; x <= n - 1; x++ ) {

                if( mineArray[y][x] == 1 ) {

                    System.out.print( "*");

                } else {

                    System.out.print( gridArray[y][x] );

                }

                if( x != n - 1 ) {

                    System.out.print( "  " );

                }

            }

            System.out.println();

        }

    }

}
```

I receive the following errors after submitting:

`Test 9: check that mines are uniformly random

- m = 1, n = 2, k = 1 [repeated 15000 times]
  value  observed  expected   2*O*ln(O/E)
  -------------------------------------------
  1-1         0    7500.0          0.00
  1-2     15000    7500.0      20794.42
  -------------------------------------------
  15000   15000.0      20794.42

  G-statistic = 20794.42 (p-value = 0.000000, reject if p-value <= 0.0001)
  Note: a correct solution will fail this test by bad luck 1 time in 10,000.
- m = 1, n = 3, k = 1 [repeated 15000 times]
  value  observed  expected   2*O*ln(O/E)
  -------------------------------------------
  1-1         0    5000.0          0.00
  1-2      7624    5000.0       6432.57
  1-3      7376    5000.0       5735.48
  -------------------------------------------
  15000   15000.0      12168.05

  G-statistic = 12168.05 (p-value = 0.000000, reject if p-value <= 0.0001)
  Note: a correct solution will fail this test by bad luck 1 time in 10,000.
- m = 2, n = 2, k = 2 [repeated 15000 times]
  value  observed  expected   2*O*ln(O/E)
  -------------------------------------------
  1-1         0    7500.0          0.00
  1-2     10044    7500.0       5867.15
  2-1      9946    7500.0       5614.86
  2-2     10010    7500.0       5779.41
  -------------------------------------------
  30000   30000.0      17261.42

  G-statistic = 17261.42 (p-value = 0.000000, reject if p-value <= 0.0001)
  Note: a correct solution will fail this test by bad luck 1 time in 10,000.
- m = 2, n = 4, k = 3 [repeated 15000 times]
  value  observed  expected   2*O*ln(O/E)
  -------------------------------------------
  1-1         0    5625.0          0.00
  1-2      6484    5625.0       1842.97
  1-3      6477    5625.0       1826.99
  1-4      6346    5625.0       1530.70
  2-1      6439    5625.0       1740.49
  2-2      6471    5625.0       1813.30
  2-3      6435    5625.0       1731.41
  2-4      6348    5625.0       1535.19
  -------------------------------------------
  45000   45000.0      12021.05

  G-statistic = 12021.05 (p-value = 0.000000, reject if p-value <= 0.0001)
  Note: a correct solution will fail this test by bad luck 1 time in 10,000.
- m = 3, n = 3, k = 6 [repeated 15000 times]
  value  observed  expected   2*O*ln(O/E)
  -------------------------------------------
  1-1         0   10000.0          0.00
  1-2     11257   10000.0       2665.77
  1-3     11278   10000.0       2712.78
  2-1     11313   10000.0       2791.31
  2-2     11228   10000.0       2600.98
  2-3     11289   10000.0       2737.44
  3-1     11171   10000.0       2474.06
  3-2     11180   10000.0       2494.07
  3-3     11284   10000.0       2726.23
  -------------------------------------------
  90000   90000.0      21202.65

  G-statistic = 21202.65 (p-value = 0.000000, reject if p-value <= 0.0001)
  Note: a correct solution will fail this test by bad luck 1 time in 10,000.

==> FAILED

Test 10: check statistical independence of mines within an m-by-n grid

- m = 500, n = 500, k = 125000
- m = 500, n = 500, k = 25000
- m = 500, n = 500, k = 225000

WARNING: the time limit of 60 seconds was exceeded, so not all tests could be completed.`

I already accounted for NOT handling above number of cell mines with my variable "totalMines" because I figured "Why not?"  I'm very stumped right now.  I come from a C++ hobbyist approach.  I've seen other answers that use a table of m+2/n+2 values which, as a wannabe solo game dev, I would consider a VERY bad practice of doing.  My personal belief is that you should only code what needs to be shown as it needs to be shown.  So, no extra table elements.  If that was done in C++ and compiled under the g++ compiler I would have to believe that, if uninitialized, those extra elements would default to garbage or NULL values and the program would SEGFAULT or interrupt.  I am probably wrong, but I need help fixing my apparent wrong approach to the problem.  Any help is GREATLY appreciated.  I would like to NOT need to simplify this if it can be helped.  I've been on this one single problem for almost two weeks and have worked about three/four hours a night for 5 nights a week on this.  Thank you!

I cannot think of anything else besides simplifying the code, but that is not my intention.

EDIT 1: We cannot use any other random function besides a uniform distribution between 0 and n - 1 (0 being cell 1 and n being amount of cells) with Math.random(). I have seen answers by using a "grid" (int[][]) with two extra elements.  As a wannabe game dev, I would not accept extra elements as an answer. Try doing that in C++ while not initializing all values to 0 first.  I guess I am just not used to Java yet.

Comment: Look at when you calculate the random row and column.

Comment: Please don't assume readers are familiar with the minesweeper game. A better question would give some explanation or background.  From reading the code, we can infer that  `args [0]` is number of rows, `args [1]` is number of columns, and `args [3]` is number of mines to distribute. But, rather than relying on us inferring that, a better question would explain that. Explaining what the code *should* do gives us a chance to compare with what the code *actually* does. This can provide a chance to detect misunderstandings.

Comment: What level of help would you like?  A lot of people here would gladly create complete code for placing mines. Of those, some would do so with an explanation, some without an explanation.  Others would rather provide feedback, find problems with your code without providing complete code.  Considering it appears to be a homework problem,  we might be interested in [How to ask and answer homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) questions.

Comment: Have you printed out the game fields after mines are laid? Do they "look" random?

Comment: If you want unbiased random integers in a range, you should be using `java.util.Random.nextInt()`.

Comment: How is this being tested? I don't see an obvious interface between your code and testing code. Is stdout from your code redirected, with the testing code examining the redirected output? Alternatively, I might expect your code to have something like a call to `evaluate (mineField)`, where `mineField` is a 2D array that holds the results. Or, IMO, better, your method is `public char [][] createMineField (int numRows, int numColumns, int numMines)`, and the test code calls your code.

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer So I am natively a C++ programmer and I firmly believe this would be better if I wrote in that vs Java.  We are limited to only using lists and basic strings.  We have not learned chars yet, nor have we learned string traversal (completely missed opportunity IMO).  At the time of posting this, I really was hoping someone would be able to gloss through this code and the errors and put their Java knowledge to better use than I can mine.  I have NOT tried to walk through the random rows mine by mine.  That is obviously a very good idea. :)  They appear random when placed.

Comment: How are those errors generated?  I missing the connection between your code and whatever it is that generates the evaluation  messages.

Comment: `Math.random()` is just a front-end for `java.util.Random.nextDouble()`. Using the former to generate integers is both less efficient than `java.util.Random.nextInt(upperLimit)`, and subject to a subtle but real source of bias. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/738651/2166798 for a nice explanation. If you're restricted from using `java.util.Random`, whoever created the restriction is doing you a disservice.

Comment: Suggestions for improving the question **+** Have a brief description of Minesweeper, or provide a (e.g.) [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minesweeper_(video_game)) at the top of the question.  **+** Remove unneeded blank lines in the code sample. (If you like, you can leave them in the code you use. But, in the embedded scroll pane here, they don't help). **+** Provide a description of how the code shown is supposed to work.

Comment: More suggestions for improving the question: **+** Remove the editorial about not liking doing the work on a grid of size `(m+2)*(n+2)`. It isn't relevant to the problem. You are not necessarily expected to copy code from answers. It is hoped you will learn from them. If an answer uses `(m+2)*(n+2)` grid, adapt that code to use your preference of an m*n grid. **+** Add at least one example input and output.

Comment: @Old Dog Programmer: Ive documented the tests from 'Test 9' and down. It appears it runs my program 15000 times or so and based on how it runs is based on statistics built into the autochecker. It keeps failing a 'p-value'. No description on what that is.

Comment: @pjs: We can't use anything not in java.lang yet. This is really an algorithms course to my knowledge. It just happens to be in, and an introduction to, Java.

Comment: I meant show sample input values and the minefield that results. In general, this is part of writing a good question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how an old dog programmer might write it.

This approach differs significantly from the O/P's. I would have *one* grid. Each cell in the grid would have either an `*` for a mine, or a digit from `0` to `8` for a non-mine. The work of placing mines and counting mines in neighboring cells would operate on that grid.

First, I'd break the job into more methods, each method being smaller.

```
public class MineSweeper {    
   final static char ASTER = '*';

   public static char [][] createMineField
                  (int numRows, int numColumns, int numMines) {

      char [][] field = new char [numRows][numColumns];
      placeMines (field, numMines);
      setCounts (field);        
      return field;
 }
```

The method `placeMines` places the mines in an empty grid. `setCounts` sets the elements of the non-mine cells to indicate how many adjacent (orthogonal and diagonal) cells contain a mine.

Suppose we use this method for placing a mine:

1. Pick a row at random.  Pick a column at random.
2. Check to see if there is collision. A collision occurs if there is already a mine at the row and column from step 1.
3. If there is a collision, go back to step 1.
4. Place the mine at the location.
5. Increment the count of mines placed.
6. If at least one more mine is needed, go to step 1.
7. Otherwise, we are finished with mine placement.

Suppose `t` is the total number of cells. That is `t = number of rows multiplied by number of columns`.  Suppose `m` is the number of mines to be placed. When `t` is high, and the ratio `m : t` is high, this method has a potential problem:  As more mines are placed, the more collisions there will be. This can slow the program. The following code always generates `t` random numbers, but avoids the collision problem. It seems wasteful if `t` is small, or the `m : t` ratio is low. But, it is guaranteed to avoid collisions:

```
public static void placeMines (char [][] grid, int numMines) {
    int size = grid.length * grid [0].length;
    int [] order = new int [size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        order [i] = i;
    }
    shuffle (order);
    
    int r, c;
    for (int i = 0; i < numMines; i++) {
        r = order [i] / grid[0].length;
        c = order [i] % grid[0].length;
        grid [r][c] = ASTER;
    }
}
public static void shuffle (int [] arr) {
    Random rand = new Random ();
    int i, j, temp;
    for (i = arr.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        j = rand.nextInt (i + 1);
        temp = arr [j];
        arr [j] = arr [i];
        arr [i] = temp;
    }              
}
```

This generates the sequence `0` to `t - 1` in an array, then shuffles the sequence. The first `m` elements of shuffled array are taken to position `m` mines.

Here is the code to fill in the rest of the grid:

```
public static void setCounts(char[][] grid) {
    int row, col, r, c, count;

    for (row = 0; row < grid.length; row++) {
        for (col = 0; col < grid[row].length; col++) {
            if (grid [row][col] == ASTER) { 
                continue;
            }

            count = 0;
            for (r = row - 1; r <= row + 1; r++) {
                for (c = col - 1; c <= col + 1; c++) {
                    if (    r >= 0           && c >= 0
                         && r <  grid.length && c < grid[row].length
                         && grid[r][c] == ASTER    ) {
                        count++;
                    }                            
                }
            }
            grid [row][col] = (char) ('0' + count);                
        }
    }
}
```

The O/P commented that he / she has not yet had a lesson with the `char`  variable type. A `char` is a 16 bit Integer type, and is one of the primitive types. But, Java assumes these values represent 16 bit Unicode characters.

The line `grid [row][col] = (char) ('0' + count);` converts the `count` value, which contains a value from 0 to 8, to the corresponding Unicode decimal digit.  This is similar to what can be done with ASCII in C, C++, and other characters.

If the O/P is not comfortable with using `char`, I suggest an `int` or `short` array instead. A mine might be represented with a "special" value outside that range, such as `-1`, `9`, or `10`.

```
     public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println("Starting program with " + args.length + " args: "
        + Arrays.toString(args) + "\n");  
       char [][] game =  createMineField (15,30, 100);
       for (int k = 0; k < game.length; k++ ) { 
           System.out.println (Arrays.toString (game[k]));
       }                
     }    
 }
```

I hard coded a single test case. An array might be used to code multiple test cases.

In keeping with the original code, the O/P might need to parse `args` from `main` to get the values to use for a single test case each run, as in the O/P code. I also used a method from `java.util.Arrays` to quickly code output. The O/P will want to provide his / her own code to meet the requirements of the autochecker.

Sample output, with 15 rows, 30 columns, and 175 mines:

```
[3, *, *, 3, 1, 1, *, 3, *, 4, *, 3, 3, *, 4, *, *, 2, 3, *, 5, *, 4, 3, *, *, *, 3, *, 2]
[*, *, *, *, 3, 3, 3, 5, *, 4, *, 4, *, *, 6, *, 5, 3, *, *, *, *, *, *, 4, 4, 3, 4, *, 2]
[4, *, *, *, *, 3, *, *, 2, 3, 2, 5, *, 5, *, *, *, 4, 5, *, 7, 6, 6, 5, *, 2, 2, *, 2, 1]
[*, 6, *, 7, *, 4, 2, 3, 2, 2, *, 5, *, 4, 2, 4, *, *, 3, *, *, *, *, *, 4, *, 4, 3, 2, 0]
[3, *, *, 6, *, 4, 1, 3, *, 3, 2, *, *, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, *, *, 4, 3, *, 5, *, *, 3, 1]
[*, 4, 4, *, *, 5, *, 5, *, 3, 2, 2, 4, *, 3, 2, *, 1, 0, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, *, *, *, *, 2]
[2, 3, *, 5, *, 7, *, *, 5, *, 2, 1, 2, *, *, 4, 3, 3, 1, 2, *, *, 3, *, *, 4, 5, *, *, 2]
[*, 4, 2, 3, *, *, *, *, *, 4, *, 1, 1, 3, 4, *, *, 5, *, 5, 5, 6, *, 4, 2, 2, *, 5, 4, 2]
[*, *, 3, 3, 3, 4, *, 4, 3, *, 4, 3, 2, 3, *, 5, *, *, *, *, *, *, *, 2, 0, 1, 3, *, *, 1]
[2, 3, *, *, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, *, *, 2, *, *, 3, 3, 5, 6, 5, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, *, 4, 2]
[0, 1, 3, *, *, 1, 1, *, *, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, *, *, *, 3, *, 2, 2, *, 3, *, 4, 3, *]
[0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 4, *, 4, 2, 2, *, 2, *, *, *, 5, 3, *, 3, 3, *, 3, 4, *, 4, *, 4]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, *, 4, 3, 4, *, *, *, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, *, 4, 3, 4, *, 3, 3, *, 2, 1, 4, *, *]
[0, 1, *, 3, *, *, *, *, *, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, *, 1, 2, *, 5, *, *, 6, *, 4, 2, 2, 0, 2, *, 3]
[0, 1, 1, 3, *, 4, 3, 3, 3, *, 2, *, *, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, *, *, *, *, *, 3, *, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```

I made all the methods static. Another approach would be to make the mine field an instance variable. The method `createMineField` could be replaced by a constructor.  The methods `placeMines` and `setCounts` could be non-static, possibly non-public, instance methods.

It would be a good idea to verify the arguments. Check the number of rows and the number of columns fall within the allowed range. Also, put a constraint on the number of mines. Consider throwing and catching  `IllegalArgumentException` for these.

Comment: Well done suggesting shuffling as the right way to distribute mines.

Comment: I discovered my shuffle code was "naïve":  Some permutations were more likely than others. I changed it based on https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-danger-of-naivete/

Comment: Did you avoid `Collections.shuffle()` because of OP's restrictions to not use anything except the `java.lang` core?

Comment: @pjs I remember thinking about using `Collections.shuffle()`, but I don't remember why I decided to code an array shuffle. In a comment, the O/P did mention using lists and strings is allowed, so I assume `Collections.shuffle()` would be allowed. If the O/P responded the array sort was a problem, I was / am prepared to change it to a `List`. As for using the `nextInt(int n)` method on a `Random` Object, I am confident the O/P can change it to use `Math.random()`.