exceeding time limit in a minesweeper program
**The Assignment : **
Minesweeper is a 1960s era video game played on an m-by-n grid of cells. The goal is to deduce which cells contain hidden mines using clues about the number of mines in neighboring cells. Write a program Minesweeper.java that takes three integer command-line arguments m, n, and k and prints an m-by-n grid of cells with k mines, using asterisks for mines and integers for the neighboring mine counts (with two space characters between each cell). To do so,
**The Desired Output : **

**The Problem : **
when I put k number close to m * n , the desired output won't be printed (it takes loooong time to generate a different index look at the code below to understand what I mean)
.
this the full code :
public class f {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int m = Integer.parseInt(args[0]); // column
        int n = Integer.parseInt(args[1]); // row
        int k = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        // true when it's a minesweeper otherwise false
        boolean[][] isT = new boolean[m + 2][n + 2];
        boolean[][] isTRand = new boolean[m + 2][n + 2];
        int countofMinesSweeper = 0;
        int[][] v = new int[m + 2][n + 2];
        // mine part :
        if (k == (m * n)) {
            for (int h = 1; h <= m; h++) {
                for (int y = 1; y <= n; y++) {
                    isT[h][y] = true;
                    countofMinesSweeper++;
                }
            }
        }
        while (countofMinesSweeper < k) {
            int mrand = (int) ((Math.random() * (m - 1))) + 1; // 1 => m
            int nrand = (int) ((Math.random() * (n - 1))) + 1; // 1 => n
            if (!isT[mrand][nrand]) {
                countofMinesSweeper++;
                isT[mrand][nrand] = true;
            }
            System.out.println(mrand);
            System.out.println(nrand);
        }
        // printing part and the cases :
        for (int c = 1; c <= m; c++) {
            for (int r = 1; r <= n; r++) {
                if (!isT[c][r]) {
                    if (isT[c][r + 1]) v[c][r]++;
                    if (isT[c][r - 1]) v[c][r]++;
                    if (isT[c + 1][r]) v[c][r]++;
                    if (isT[c - 1][r]) v[c][r]++;
                    if (isT[c - 1][r + 1]) v[c][r]++;
                    if (isT[c - 1][r - 1]) v[c][r]++;
                    if (isT[c + 1][r + 1]) v[c][r]++;
                    if (isT[c + 1][r - 1]) v[c][r]++;
                }
                if (isT[c][r]) {
                    System.out.print(" * ");
                }
                else {
                    System.out.print(" " + v[c][r] + " ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}


note : I think the cause of the problem is the two random numbers I tried to figure out another solution that doesn't use randoms but I failed .

Offtopic, but… I did not realize there were any 1960s era video games.

Off-topic:  @VGR I noticed that, too. Wikipedia says Minesweeper was released in 1990, but based on a game from 1983. There were video games in the 1960s, but they had displays like oscilloscopes, or CRTs connected to mainframe computers.

Off-topic: An interesting thing about playing Minesweeper is that the player is guaranteed to clear a non-mine cell on the first move. Does that imply the mines are actually placed after the first move but before the second?

Before reading my answer or others' answers to other question(s), please do the following: (1) Read and consider How to Ask and Answer Homework Questions. (2) Consider why your program is running so slowly: What happens if you want to place 899 mines into a 30x30 grid? Your program might have to try thousands attempts just to place the last mine. (3) Try to think of a way to place mines generating m*n random numbers.

I previously answered a question about Minesweeper. One of the problems the person who wrote the question had was his / her program was taking too long to place mines.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77118571/how-to-randomly-distribute-mines-for-a-minesweeper-program/77124506#77124506

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

Since console output is textual data, it should be posted as code-formatted text rather than images.

There is a problem with your code, so (a-1) 9 9 64 OK (a-2) 9 9 65 Never END. (b-1) 8 4 21 OK, (b-2) 8 4 22 Never END. (c) The K of your current program must be less than or equal to (m-1) * (n-1) to run normally. As long as it is greater than (m-1) * (n-1) It won't end. (d) The root cause and my solution are in the answers below.

Only these two lines of code need to be modified:
(1) int mrand = (int) ((Math.random() * m)) + 1; // 1 => m
(2) int nrand = (int) ((Math.random() * n)) + 1; // 1 => n

Your Code Block
while (countofMinesSweeper < k) {
    int mrand = (int) ((Math.random() * (m - 1))) + 1; // 1 => m
    int nrand = (int) ((Math.random() * (n - 1))) + 1; // 1 => n
    if (!isT[mrand][nrand]) {
        countofMinesSweeper++;
        isT[mrand][nrand] = true;
    }
    
    // System.out.println(mrand);
    // System.out.println(nrand);
    
    System.out.println(mrand+"\t"+ nrand);
}

I've changed the code here to find a few things better.
System.out.println(mrand+"\t"+ nrand);

application input parameter: 8 4 31
Your code never ends.
Because there is an error in your code:
7   1
2   3
2   1
6   3
1   2
5   3
7   3
7   1
2   3
7   3
2   2
1   2
6   3
2   1
6   2
1   3
2   2
3   3
2   3
7   2
5   1

input m=8 , n=4 , k=31

but your first num (m) always 1~7 , not include 8.
and your second num (n) always 1~3, not include 4.

your code always fill 7 * 3 = 21, but when you put k=31,  it never reaches 31.
you can test your input.

input 8 4 21 ( 21 = 7 x 3) , your code will run very fast.

input 8 4 22 ( 22 = 21+1,  21 = 7 x 3) , it will never end. (your code always get random (1~7),(1~3), never get row column 8,4)


This is the root cause.
Your array start from 1 not from 0.
But when you set column or row, the length is -1
then correct range:
m (1~8), n(1~4).
but your code range:
m (1~7), n(1~3)
When K <= your code range (7 * 3), work fine.
But when K > your code range (7 * 3), then while loop never end.
CORRECT CODE
while (countofMinesSweeper < k) {
    //int mrand = (int) ((Math.random() * (m - 1))) + 1; // 1 => m
    //int nrand = (int) ((Math.random() * (n - 1))) + 1; // 1 => n
    int mrand = (int) ((Math.random() * (m))) + 1; // 1 => m
    int nrand = (int) ((Math.random() * (n))) + 1; // 1 => n

    if (!isT[mrand][nrand]) {
        countofMinesSweeper++;
        isT[mrand][nrand] = true;
    }
    
    //System.out.println(mrand);
    //System.out.println(nrand);
                
    System.out.println(mrand+"\t"+ nrand);
}

